# Typescript add missing import on cursor?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lsp

I'm working on a TypeScript-React project using neovim, because I love it. I want a feature: when my cursor is on a name that has not been imported, I can press some key-combination to choose which library I would like to import. E.g.

Input:

```
import { Head } from "next/head"
import { Another } from "./another"


export default function Home() {
  const foo = <Another/>
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
```

Output:

```
import { Head } from "next/head"


export default function Home() {
  const foo = <Another/>
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
```

What I've tried:

- I installed a plugin, [vim-import-js](https://github.com/Galooshi/vim-import-js), that works well on importing javascript module. But it doesn't work on `.ts` and `.tsx`.

I know very little about Lua, LSP, `.tsconfig.json`, and `eslintrc.js`. It seems like these files also need to be set to make these plugins to work. I will also appreciate if you can provide more context on how these settings are referenced to make things work.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Kindly updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I assume the following according to your post + image:

- You're using neovim >= 0.5.0
- You've already set up the server with (assuming that the following code is in a lua file like `~/.config/nvim/lua/rofl.lua` and you're loading it in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` with `lua require('rofl')`):

```lua
local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')
nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup({})
```

According to the [README.md](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#keybindings-and-completion) of [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) you just need to add the following mapping in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
nnoremap <Space>a <Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>
```

or if you have a `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` or any other `*.lua` file:

```lua
buf_set_keymap('n', '<space>a', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>', opts)
```

After that you should get a little dialog if you press `<Space>` and then `a` where you can decide which one to import. At least that works for me. I don't know that much about these extra-config files because the settings above worked for me out of the box (like the code action).

Comment: [“assuming that the following code is in a lua file like `~/.config/nvim/lua/rofl.lua`”] ==> I know nothing about the project structure of `~/.config/nvim`. Could you recommend any learning resource, please?

Comment: It still doesn't work. I got message: no code action available.

Comment: oh ok wait, so you're a completely beginner in (neo)vim?

Comment: ["so you're a completely beginner in (neo)vim?"] ==> I have a huge(somehow organized) .vimrc, but I know nothing about `init.vim` and Lua. (and I know very little on writing vimscript actually.)

Comment: Alright, give me some time, I'll edit my post

Comment: Hm... or wait, could you please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOjVHXaUrzo first? It could help you

Comment: I'm really happy that you recommended him, but I'm already his fan, and indeed I've watched this one :) My vim journey started from there.

Comment: Hm... ok, I'd recommend you to read through the `':h` pages. It seems to be a lot, but that's the fastest way (in my opinion) to get an overview of all features of vim. `:h runtimepath` will explain you the directory-structure of vim for example.